# Getting all columns in a list with the same tablename

Tags: python, list

I am trying to retrieve a list of columns per tablename

Let's say I have the following table

```
('tableA', 'columnA', 1)
('tableA', 'columnB', 2)
('tableB', 'columnA', 1)
('tableB', 'columnB', 2)
('tableC', 'columnA', 1)
('tableD', 'columnA', 1)
```

how can I return a list grouped by the same tablename?
So it returns the following

```
('tableA', 'columnA', 'columnB')
('tableB', 'columnA', 'columnB')
('tableC', 'columnA')
('tableD', 'columnA')
```

Comment: You need to give more details, like what type of database are you using?

Comment: Did you try out some code over the same question? Any snippet?

Comment: You can use dictionary with key as table

Comment: i used pyodbc to create a list item for each row with the query: get_data_from_table = cursor.fetchall(). It returns a list like i posted in the original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this. Note that this requires the list to be sorted by table name first, but in your case it seems to be, anyway. Otherwise, sort it first.

```
get_data_from_table.sort() # only if not already sorted
tables = [[key] + [g[1] for g in groups] 
          for (key, groups) in itertools.groupby(get_data_from_table, 
                                                 key=operator.itemgetter(0))]
```

Or use a dictionary (or [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)), mapping table names to columns:

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for t, c, n in get_data_from_table:
    d[t].append(c)
tables = [[key] + values for key, values in d.items()]
```